# Command Substitution with Android.mk

Tags: bash, shell, android-ndk, android.mk

I have come across the command in an Android.mk file that I am working with:

```
include $(DEPENDENCIES_NANOBUFFERS_DIR)/android/jni/include.mk
```

I understand that $(command) is "command substitution". It runs a command, captures it's output, and inserts that into the command line that contains $(  )

However I've searched the entire Android.mk file to find what the command DEPENDENCIES_NANOBUFFERS_DIR stands for and I haven't found any meaning for it.

I know that NANOBUFFERS is a file in my dependencies directory, since I manually searched through all the files contained in my root directory. The is a file named dependencies and within this file is my  NANOBUFFERS file. However if DEPENDENCIES_NANOBUFFERS_DIR is not  specified explicitly how is the compiler able to find the correct pathway to include.mk? Is this done automatically?

DEPENDENCIES_NANOBUFFERS_DIR occurs in only one other place and that is at the bottom of the Android.mk file.

```
$(call import-add-path,$(DEPENDENCIES_NANOBUFFERS_DIR)/..)
```

Can someone please explain how the compiler interprets DEPENDENCIES_NANOBUFFERS_DIR even when this command isn't specfied anywhere in the Android.mk file? Thank you in advance.

Comment: That is not command substitution in a makefile, it is a macro-name, probably a variable.  Macros names of more than one character require braces { } when substituted, single character names do not (although it is still a good idea).  Parentheses ( ) may also be used, but in some versions of make they have special a meaning when handling libraries.  It could all be an environment variable available as a macro inside a makefile.

Comment: makefile and bash are different lanugages with different syntax, in makefile $(foo) is a variable reference like ${foo}

Comment: There might be an earlier `include` which defines `DEPENDENCIES_NANOBUFFERS_DIR`

Comment: I just found that DEPENDENCIES_NANOBUFFERS_DIR is defined in a completely different file which is in a different module. So that clears up this confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This following code links to another Android.mk file which is in a different file which is in a different module

```
include $(DIFFERENT_DIR)/buildtool/android_common.mk
```

Within this android_common.mk the variable DEPENDENCIES_NANOBUFFERS_DIR is assigned it's pathway